# Django: How to filter related objects based on different criteria?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a 'workflow management website' where different workflows with different steps can be tracked. A workflow is defined by a number of steps with a given order. A 'Job' realizes the workflow and 'Tasks' realize the steps.

```
class Workflow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'),max_length = 100, unique = True)

class Step(models.Model):
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(
        Workflow,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length = 100)
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(_('Reihenfolge'))

class Job(models.Model):
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(
        Workflow,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def current_task(self):
        # first task without finished date
        my_tasks = self.task_set\
                .filter(finished__isnull=True)\
                .order_by('step__order')
        if my_tasks.exists():
            return my_tasks.first() 
        return False


class Task(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(
        Job,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    step = models.ForeignKey(
        'Step',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    assigned_to  = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

The current task of a workflow is the 'first' task without a 'finished' date (ordering is given by task.step.order). If there is no such task, the job is finished.

My question is how to filter current tasks for a number of jobs. For example, I want to filter Jobs where the current task is assigned_to some user. So far I used a for-loop and checked `job.current_task().assigned_to` for each job, but this obviously is a pretty slow/dumb way of doing that. Is there a more efficient way?

I could, of course, add an additional relationship (not DRY) which points from Job to the current task, but that shouldn't be necessary?

EDIT: Here is my current approach for filtering jobs (given by 'queryset') where the current task is assigned to 'myuser':

```
for job in queryset:
    if not job.current_task() or not job.current_task().assigned_to == myuser:
        exclude.append(job.id)
queryset_filtered = queryset.exclude(id__in=exclude)
```

Comment: paste your model code also

Comment: Model code is included!? Relevant section should be there.

Answer (score 0):

To get all jobs with unfinished tasks that are assigned to the user `myuser`:

```
Job.objects.filter(task__finished__isnull=True, task__assigned_to=myuser)
```

Comment: This should get me all jobs where ANY unfinished task is assigned to myuser, but I want all jobs where the current (as defined above) task is assigned to myuser. Ideally, I'd somehow get a queryset of 'current tasks' for given jobs. Then I could do the necessary processing on this queryset.

Comment: Not sure I understand what exactly you want to do, could you update the question with your current solution involving the for-loop where you use your models?